# BASH AWK Script add days to fixed date

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, date

My task is to export data from a database with the UNLOAD TO statement in dbaccess and convert it into a file, that can be inserted into a similar database.

Now the problem:

The old database (let's call it DB1) has some dates in it stored in minutes starting from 01.01.1993. So, for example, 11.980.800 minutes would be today. Now I need to take that value and convert it to a date in the format `%d.%m.%Y`, so it fits in the row in the new database (DB2), which accepts only DATE as value.

The exported data from DB1 is separated by `^`. I have some relevant `if` statements for other rows, but I just can't handle the rows with the DATE value as I wrote already. The print statement looks like this:

```
print "INSERT INTO zdv_voa(voa_fnr, voa_kritkz, voa_krit, voa_kz, voa_datv, voa_datb, voa_grund) VALUES("$1",\'"$2"\',\'"$3"\',\'"$4"\',"$5","$6",\'"$7"\');"
```

where `$5` and `$6` are the minutes that need to be converted to dates.

After I run the awk script, I need a file with:

```
INSERT INTO zdv_voa(voa_fnr, voa_kritkz, voa_krit, voa_kz, **voa_datv**, **voa_datb**, voa_grund) VALUES(1,'P','148','T','10.10.2015','02.07.1999','60');
```

The dates used here are just examples and the other values are already converted by me.

Comment: `date -d '01/01/1993 +11980800 minutes' +%d.%m.%Y` will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how many seconds elapse from epoch to Jan,1 1993 ?

```
date -d '01/01/1993' +%s
```

## strftime

you can test if you awk allow `strftime()`

```
echo 11980000 | awk '{u=60*$1+725842800 ; printf "%d -> %s\n",u, strftime("%x",u); } '
```

this return  `10/12/2015`

now in your code add

```
dollar5=strftime("%x",60*$5+725842800) ;
# $6 is left as an exercice ..
print "INSERT INTO zdv_voa(voa_fnr, voa_kritkz, voa_krit, voa_kz, voa_datv, voa_datb, voa_grund) VALUES("$1",\'"$2"\',\'"$3"\',\'"$4"\',\'"dollar5"\',\'"dollar6"\',\'"$7"\');"
```